# Adding ViewController to existing UINavigation stack

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller

How to present modal ViewController on top of UINavigationController without using initWithRootViewController, just with adding it to the existing navigationcontroller stack?

my code is:

```
TableViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableView"];
UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[self presentViewController:navi animated:NO completion:nil];
```

edit: what i actually want is to do like: "vc1 push vc2 modal vc3" and than use "poptoroot...to vc1". But the initWithRootViewController (vc3) is ruining it.

Comment: present modal and adding to an existing navigationController are mutual exclusive. Maybe you are looking for `[self.navigationController pushViewController: controller animated:YES];`?!

Comment: i dont want to use push. the code works perfectly at is. what i actually want is to do like: "vc1 push vc2 modal vc3" and than use "poptoroot...to vc1". But the initWithRootViewController (vc3) is ruining it.

Comment: try presenting your controller instead of navi

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the stack of navigationController. Use :

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // If animated is YES, then simulate a push or pop depending on whether the new top view controller was previously in the stack.
```

It will help.